# pyodbc error "SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error set"

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

I was developing a reporting dashboard using Django. I'm pulling data from an outer database (ms SQL server 2012) using ***django-pyodbc-azure***. I was facing a weird problem when I pulling data in my localhost using ***manage.py runserver*** it can pull the data from the database but when I run the same query in my production server its returns this error. The query is a bit big it takes 50 seconds + time.

> SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error
> set

my production server is ubuntu 18.4 and Nginx.

I do a few google searches but not find any answer.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing a very similar problem